# Heroku cannot open browser to log in

Tags: heroku

I tried to log into Heroku via my command prompt by typing `heroku login` but this happened:

[image: Screenshot of the issue]

It says it cannot open my browser to log in. How should I proceed?

Comment: You could update Heroku to check if that fixes it. If it does not fix it I would add an issue to the project https://github.com/heroku. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This just means that the Heroku CLI is having trouble opening the URL shown in your terminal for you.

Copy that URL and paste it into a browser of your choice, then log in.